# How can I clear the third div like the above 2 divs?

Tags: html, css

here is what i'm trying to solve...

```
<div class="post">

    <div class="date">
        <div class="day">01</div>
        <div class="month">Jan</div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-info">
    <h2><a href="#">Donec commodo et justo ac bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametit</a></h2>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="post">

    <div class="date">
        <div class="day">01</div>
        <div class="month">Jan</div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-info">
    <h2><a href="#">Donec commodo et justo ac bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></h2>
    </div>

</div>

        <div class="post">

            <div class="date">
                <div class="day">01</div>
                <div class="month">Jan</div>
            </div>

            <div class="post-info">
            <h2><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis mi tellus, at venenatis justo fermentum at. Ut sed nulla leo. Quisque pulvinar massa ut velit porttitor imperdiet. Ut sit amet sollicitudin lacus, at tincidunt mauris. Donec commodo et justo ac bibendum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis mi tellus, at venenatis justo fermentum at. Ut sed nulla leo. Quisque pulvinar massa ut velit porttitor imperdiet. Ut sit amet sollicitudin lacus, at tincidunt mauris. Donec commodo et justo ac bibendum. </a></h2>
            </div>

        </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kaZ6H/1/

I want the 3rd div's content to be cleared like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Zcp.jpg

I don't want to apply height for the elements.Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: which 3rd div? you have like 30 divs here? and what do you mean by clear?

Comment: I mean the last div with the class="post"}
Please see the screenshot and jsfiddle snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the divs a display of table cell:

```
.date, .post-info {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kaZ6H/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.post{
    margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 15px 0px;
    display: table;
}

.post .date{
    font-size:18px;
    margin:0px 25px 0px 25px;
    line-height:22px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.post-info{
    width:780px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Well, you basically are telling the browser that those elements should display like a table. So, .post is the containing table, and .date and .post-info are cells inside that table. This will display the elements as a table, but you will still have a valid markup for search engines :) you only get the displaying of the table, but not the markup of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `.post h2` class from

```
.post h2 {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:24px;
}
```

to

```
.post h2 {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:24px;
    padding-left: 75px; /*added this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using percentage instead. You set the container `post`'s width and then setting the width of the `post-info` to the maximum width minus the width of the date div.

**[JSFiddle exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/kaZ6H/5/)**

```
.post{
    margin:0px 0px 25px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 15px 0px;
    width: 780;
}

.post-info{
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the right div the style "display:inline-block".

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/A9wW2/

```
.post-info{
width:780px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```